# When to use the base Vue instance, Vuex or mixin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In Vue, you can store commonly used variables and methods in the base Vue instance. This way other components can access this data.

```
new Vue({
    data: {
        name: 'John'
    }
});
```

If you are using Vuex for state management you could also store this data here as well.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
       name: 'John'
    }
}
```

From my understanding, Vue mixins also offer the same functionality (allowing any component to access this commonly shared data globally).

```
Vue.mixin({
    data() {
        return {
            name: 'John'
        };
    }
});
```

My question is when should you use the base Vue instance over Vuex or a global mixin?

Comment: 1) The `data` property in the root `Vue` instance should **not** be a function. 2) The mixin data will not be _shared_, it will be merged into a component's data each time it is created. 3) Any answer to question will be opinion-based as the question itself is too broad / subjective

Comment: Good catch. Will update it now. Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that any of the methods I listed above can be used for the same purpose (sharing data across the application)? I was hoping maybe there is a specific scenario to use one over the other.

Comment: It entirely depends on what you're trying to build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Vuex` is a very sophisticated state management solution catering to Redux like `Unidirectional/one-way` data flow architecture. Use it when you need to share data across components in a sophisticated way where you need to also handle side-effects. You can also say that `Vuex` is nothing but a glorified implementation of `Vue` instance.

Vue instance, a.k.a., Vue component is meant to model your UI component. Yes, it can also serve as a State Manager and global Event Bus. But use it only for smaller apps and POC. Otherwise, `Vuex` is always the right choice.

Now talking about `Mixins`. It is not really a state management mechanism. It is meant to share reusable functionality across different components. Typically using mixins to only have `data()` is not a good design though. It must also have some methods that should act on that data. This is where mixins fit in overall Vue ecosystem.

Comment: I basically use Mixins for a constant type of data. meaning a global constant which I am aware does not change. I wouldn't use Vuex for such because I regard it as a state management storage